# tkinter como alterar cor do texto

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Como eu faço para modificar a cor de um label para deixar o fundo preto e as letras em branco ?

Eu pesquisei e o que eu encontrei foi a opção de mudar o background para preto no entanto além do background do label também mudou a cor das letras.

O código que estou usando no momento é:

```
text1 = tk.Label(text='texto teste', background='black')
```

Porém dessa forma tudo fica preto e consequentemente não aparece já que minha aplicação tem o fundo preto.

Aqui a forma que fica usando vermelho como exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você adicionar o parâmetro `foreground` na criação do `label` que é usado para textos e labels bitmap.

Portanto basta você alterar de:

```
text1 = tk.Label(text='texto teste', background='black')
```

Para:

```
text1 = tk.Label(text='texto teste', background='black', foreground='white')
```

[Exemplo funcionando](https://repl.it/@sant0will/DefiniteWrongLists)

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado.

Answer (score -3):

text1 = tk.Label(text='texto teste', background='black', foreground='white')

iai maninho....
vc pode usar pra abreviar desse jeito:

text1 = tk.Label(text='texto teste', bg= 'black', fg= 'white')